# Problem Trying to Bake a Normal Map To Access Blue Values of the Normal Map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I am trying to bake a normal map for this object but it isn't working.  I am basically trying to add dust to an object by just accessing the blue values (the values that are upward facing on the normal map so that I can add dust just to the top of the model) through a separate RGB node once I have a normal map as shown in this picture:
[image]

I am not trying bake from high poly, to low poly, rather just trying to create a normal map for the object itself.  I included the UV unwrap I did and the image that comes out after I bake is completely blue which would suggest that my model is at the same angle as the normal map that's trying to be created but that's impossible because of how spherical my object is.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You don't need a normal map to access the normal vector of the face. Is there a reason why you would like to bake it?

Comment: So I want to access all of the upward facing vectors. I thought I had to do a normal map to do it because when I tried to it without a normal map, I couldn’t get just the upward values, I got the normals for example coming on the bottom of the arm and that’s not where you would expect to see dust if that makes sense? @Carlo

Comment: Did you check the CLAMP option in the color mix node as shown in the tutorial? That should prevent negative Z values from being take into account.

Comment: I did yes @Carlo